# How to change year format

Tags: r, date

I have a year column in my dataframe, which is formatted as financial year (e.g. 2015-16, 2016-17, etc). I want to change them to just 4-digit year in such a way that 2015-16 becomes 2016; 2016-17 becomes 2017, etc. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parse_number` from `readr` :

```
x <- c('2015-16', '2016-17')
readr::parse_number(x) + 1
#[1] 2016 2017
```

`parse_number` drops any non-numeric characters before or after the first number.  So in this example, everything after the first number is dropped and turned to numeric. We then add 1 to to it to get next year.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution can be,

```
as.numeric(sub('-.*', '', '2015-16')) + 1
#[1] 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to capture the first two digits while leaving the next two digits and the `-`, and in the replacement, specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
as.numeric(sub("^(\\d{2})\\d{2}-", "\\1", v1))
#[1] 2016 2017
```

Or more compactly match the two digits followed by the `-`, and replace with blank (`''`)

```
sub("\\d{2}-", "", v1)
[1] "2016" "2017"
```

---

Or using `substr`

```
paste0(substr(v1,1, 2), substr(v1, 6, 7))
#[1] "2016" "2017"
```

NOTE: None of the solutions require any external packages.  Also, it doesn't implicitly assume there is always an increment of 1 year.  It can be any year range as below and it works

```
v2 <- c("2015-18", "2014-15", "2012-19")
sub("\\d{2}-", "", v2)
#[1] "2018" "2015" "2019"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("2015-16", "2016-17")
```